# How can I create a field that has two fields?

Tags: laravel-backpack

Started using the translation package in Backpack. I thought that it would be nice and easy to use, but to be honest, it's quite a pain to use. I don't want to switch page to change the language.

I want to make my own custom field that will show a "name_french" and a "name_english" attribute. This way, you can fill both of them at the same time and see them both at the same time. Of course, I will do some work in the backend to make it fit the package.

Is there an easy way to do this? Is there a way to make a Backpack field be actually two fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, you can either

(A) [create a custom field type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type-1), but you'd need to do that for all types of fields you want to be translatable;

or

(B) use [the repeatable field](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#repeatable-1), that will allow you to basically have a form with two columns, one for each language, with various types of inputs;

Comment: Thank you! I ended up creating a custom field type with a "xxx_french" and a "xxx_english" field.